# How to enable run time compilation for spring web application in Intellij?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-14

I want to  build spring web application in Intellij but each time I make changes in my code I need to restart the server and run it again to reflect the changes. Is there any way to configure the run time compilation mode in Intellij so there will be no need to restart the server again and again?